# Morita Equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb C$ be the field of complex mumbers and let $\mathbb Z$ be the rational integers. Assume that $R\subset\mathbb C$ is a ring finitely generated over $\mathbb Z$. Is it true that $R$ and $\mathbb Z$ are Morita equivalent?

Comment: What led you to think this might be true--out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not. Morita equivalent rings have isomorphic centers. So, taking $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is a counterexample (the latter isn't integrally closed).

Comment: More to the point, two commutative rings are isomorphic if and only if they are Morita equivalent, and there are plenty of finitely-generated subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ that are not isomorphic to the integers.